# Why isn't the browser autocompleting the whole HTML Form?

Tags: html, forms, autofill

I have an HTML form with 3 simple inputs and a submit button like this:

```
<form action="foo.php" method="post" id="form" name="form" target="_blank" autocomplete="on">
    <input type="text" value="" name="firstname" id="firstname" placeholder="First Name" autocomplete="firstname" />
    <input type="text" value="" name="lastname" id="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" autocomplete="lastname" />
    <input type="email" value="" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" autocomplete="email" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="send" />
</form>
```

When I click on the First Name input though and select the First Name to auto-complete, the browser doesn't complete the rest of the form (Last Name and Email). Using the Latest Chrome build: 90.0.44

Is that an expected behavior? How can I make the browser to autofill the whole form?

Answer (score 0):

There is a description of autocomplete attributes here. [MDN web docs - autocomplete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete).

> "given-name"
> The given (or "first") name.

> "family-name"
> The family (or "last") name.

`email` is the correct identifier for it tho.  try correcting the others and see if that works for you.

Comment: I just checked it. When I change it to the above it doesn't even offer me anything to select from.